# GeoIP2 specify IP to query

Tags: javascript, geoip, maxmind

How do I specify the IP address to query, using the MaxMind GeoIP JavaScript API? It should be really trivial, but I can't find it anywhere in their documentation.

This is the function that I use, but it automatically queries my own IP address. I would like to specify a different IP address to be queried.

```
geoip2.country(onSuccess, onError);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MaxMind GeoIP2 JavaScript API only returns the information for the current device, using the IP address with which the device connects to the MaxMind server. There is no way to pass it an arbitrary IP address.

I can't tell if you are doing frontend or backend JS, but on the backend you could use something [geoip2ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip2ws) for web service access or [maxmind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maxmind) to query a local GeoIP2/GeoLite2 databse.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an IP2Country method on the wfUtils object?

In PHP I do this.

```
global $geo_location;
$ip = wfUtils::getIP();
$geo_location = wfUtils::IP2Country($ip);
if ($geo_location === 'US') {...}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but it seems that in JavaScript API there is no such function. There are only 3 functions for each plan that you can purchase and all of them have options parameter. geoip2.country(onSuccess, onError, options); but in the official documentation there is not specified what it is for.